# Azure Table Query issues

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to upgrade the MS PnP CQRS project to the latest Azure SDK and I have the following 2 queries:

```
var query = new TableQuery<EventTableServiceEntity>().Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, UnpublishedRowKeyPrefix),
        TableOperators.And,
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, UnpublishedRowKeyPrefixUpperLimit)))
            .Select(x => new { x.PartitionKey })
            .AsTableQuery();

var query2 = eventTableServiceEntities
    .Where(
        x =>
            String.Compare(x.RowKey, UnpublishedRowKeyPrefix, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0 &&
            String.Compare(x.RowKey, UnpublishedRowKeyPrefixUpperLimit, StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0)
   .Select(x => new { x.PartitionKey }).AsTableQuery();
```

The 1st one doesn't error (the query I think is wrong anyway) The 2nd one is the original one and that now errors with `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

1: what is the issue with the 2nd query? Is this style not supported anymore? I haven't even gotten to the point where it's being executed!

2: What is the 2nd query doing and how would I represent that in the style of query 1 if the linq style is resigned.

Here is the original code:

https://github.com/mspnp/cqrs-journey/blob/master/source/Infrastructure/Azure/Infrastructure.Azure/EventSourcing/EventStore.cs#L215

The sort of stuff I am confused about here is

```
x.RowKey.CompareTo(UnpublishedRowKeyPrefix) >= 0
```

Where `UnpublishedRowKeyPrefix` is:

```
private const string UnpublishedRowKeyPrefix = "Unpublished_";
```

How can you compare that meaningfuly? What am I missing?!

eventTableServiceEntities is from here - I created a variable to aid debugging:

https://github.com/dpiessens/cqrs-journey-code/blob/master/source/Infrastructure/Azure/Infrastructure.Azure/EventSourcing/EventStore.cs#L213

```
var eventTableServiceEntities= new TableQuery<EventTableServiceEntity>();
var query2 = eventTableServiceEntities
            .Where(
                x =>
                String.Compare(x.RowKey, UnpublishedRowKeyPrefix, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0 &&
                String.Compare(x.RowKey, UnpublishedRowKeyPrefixUpperLimit, StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0)
            .Select(x => new { x.PartitionKey })
            .AsTableQuery();
```

Comment: Did you try removing the last .Select and the .AsTableQuery(); from the first query?

Comment: The 1st query works..

Comment: What is eventTableServiceEntities? Why not use new TableQuery like in the above?

Comment: So I'm upgrading the cqrs code from the MS PnP project. TBH the code doesn't make sense to me as its asking for equal to or greater than on a string! I was thinking about this last night and one thing I considered was that they're overload on the equality operator somewhere for this. Haven't had a chance to look yet though. And it's a long shot :)

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft I have updated my q - I'm quite confused atm with all this! For now I've reverted to using the non-azure stuff because of this glitch but I'd obviously really want to get back onto azure with it :)

Comment: @iwayneo As I asked above, what is eventTableServiceEntities? What is it set to at the time you run execute the second query?

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft have updated the question - I pulled the code form another branch where someone else has attempted to update the project. I've linked to that branch / code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string comparison you provided works in the following manner:
when you filter on values >= "a" and < "b", you will get back all strings that start with "a". So for your example, it looks like the filter is for all strings that start with "Unpublished_" but are lower than the UnpublishedRowKeyPrefixUpperLimit you have set. As for help with crafting Linq queries, this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/announcing-storage-client-library-2-1-rtm.aspx) should help you understand the differences between Fluent mode and the newer IQueriable mode for writing queries and how to convert from one to the other. (Relevant content is halfway down the page.)